# Allocate memory for vector<vector<> > the short way

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I'm writing a class where I need a 2D Array and want to use 2D vectors. However, I need to declare the 2D Array first as private and allocate the memory then in my constructor. When I'm doing it the following way I get a "call of an object of a class type without appropriate operator() or conversion functions to pointer-to-function type" Error. Could anyone help me?

```
class Test {

private:
    vector<vector<unsigned int> > DynTable;

public:
    Test(const string &s1, const string &s2) {
        const size_t len1 = s1.size(), len2 = s2.size();
        DynTable(len1 + 1, vector<unsigned int>(len2 + 1));
```

Comment: You know that `vector<vector<>>` is usually a slow idea, unless it is const? Due to the way elements are created, your inner vector will be copied quite often, if you modify things. It is usually faster to use a one dimensional array and a mapping of x-y-coordinates to linear coordinates.

Comment: Okay, that may be but is not a problem right now. The strings I work with are kinda short ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DynTable` is a variable. Your code is like doing:

```
int y;
y(5);
```

The expression *variablename* `(` *expression* `)` means to call a function. But `y` and `DynTable` are not functions, hence the error.

I think you meant to use a ctor-initializer list:

```
Test(const string &s1, const string &s2)
    : DynTable( s1.size() + 1, vector<unsigned int>(s2.size() + 1) )
{
    // other code here perhaps
}
```

In the ctor-initializer list it is not expressions, it is initialization syntax. In the context of initialization lists, the `( )` delimit arguments to be used for initializing the variable.

Another option would be to write, in the constructor body,

```
DynTable = vector<vector<unsigned int>>(len1 + 1, vector<unsigned int>(len2 + 1));
```

however this is worse because it is more typing, and it does a default construction and then an assignment instead of just constructing what you want directly.

Comment: Ah, yes of course, such a stupid fail. Thanks for the nice explanation, helped me alot :)